# Springboot application deployment to EKS

Tags: amazon-eks, eksctl

We are seeing issues while creating an Ingress for a springboot application in EKS.
We are following the available AWS documentation while trying to create the Ingress.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-alb-ingress-controller-setup/

While checking the logs, we are seeing the permission errors for a serviceAccount being able to access the its service.
Please see the logs below. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

{"level":"error","ts":1614308496.6815305,"logger":"controller","msg":"Reconciler error","controller":"ingress","name":"ingress-2048","namespace":"game-2048","error":"couldn't auto-discover subnets: WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials\ncaused by: AccessDenied: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity\n\tstatus code: 403, request id: fda38613-cded-49ba-9542-624962ffdb80"}
{"level":"error","ts":1614308506.9275057,"logger":"controller","msg":"Reconciler error","controller":"ingress","name":"ingress-2048","namespace":"game-2048","error":"couldn't auto-discover subnets: WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials\ncaused by: AccessDenied: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity\n\tstatus code: 403, request id: 73c54038-3259-4e04-8e44-930bccdc6ac0"}
{"level":"error","ts":1614308527.413746,"logger":"controller","msg":"Reconciler error","controller":"ingress","name":"ingress-2048","namespace":"game-2048","error":"couldn't auto-discover subnets: WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials\ncaused by: AccessDenied: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity\n\tstatus code: 403, request id: 4281835c-e491-4a64-9926-df5f22d2b630"}
{"level":"error","ts":1614308568.3853583,"logger":"controller","msg":"Reconciler error","controller":"ingress","name":"ingress-2048","namespace":"game-2048","error":"couldn't auto-discover subnets: WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials\ncaused by: **AccessDenied: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity\n\tstatus code: 403, request id: f5ceec2c-a163-49a1-ba24-810c556278b8"}**